# Apply transformations in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector, transform

I've made some transforms to a vector shape in Indesign and would now like to 'finally apply them' so that this transformed shape becomes the standard base shape I can work from moving forward. I can find 'Clear Transforms' but I can't find an 'Apply Transforms' button? Thanks.

Comment: There is no apply transform. You just stop transforming and that's it. It's super unclear to me what you want to do to the transformation with this "apply transform".

Comment: Perhaps this is something you should ultimately do in Illustrator.  Sure InDesign can do vectors, but it falls short compared to Illustrator when it comes to manipulating vectors. In Illustrator for example, one would generally use Expand Appearance on an object with a transform. Why do you need to apply the transforms? What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?  At the moment your question reads a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Object->Paths->Close Path will typically give you the same results as "Expand" in Illustrator... It just depends on the transformations that you've made.

Comment: What sort of "transformations" are you referring to?